# Google Play ask for deobfuscation txt file, Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, google-play, visual-studio-2019, android-r8

When I previously released my application it went well, but now I try to upload a new version of my application and Google Play says that it has some java/kotlin code in it and asks for me to upload an deobfuscation txt file. I have been looking for answers and the people mention a "mapping.txt" file which android studio creates when you are using proguard or R8 code shrinkers.

Does anyone know where I can generate such file or where it may be?

**Note:** I haven't added or upgraded any nuget packages since the last time I updated the application and I already looked in the bin/obj folders with no luck. Also I checked the archive folder that creates when I bundle the application.

Answer (score 2):

The obfuscation step of ProGuard is disabled when building a Xamarin Android application. Therefore, there's no deobfuscation file generated and no need to upload one. You can ignore the warning.

From the [Xamarin.Android documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/release-prep/proguard):

> The Xamarin.Android ProGuard configuration does not obfuscate the APK. In fact, it is not possible to enable obfuscation through ProGuard (even through the use of custom configuration files).

**Edit:** There is currently an [open PR](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/pull/5304) in Xamarin.Android to have ProGuard generate the `mapping.txt` file. Note that this is only to silence the warning, though. In theory, it's not needed.

Comment: but r8 is definitely doing obfuscation. my crash reports are obfuscated in google play store